# Richardson Iteration

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

> Given the Richardson Iteration, $x_{n+1} = x_n + \alpha(b-Ax_n)$ (with
>   $\alpha$ a scalar constant). To which polynomial $p(A)$ at step $n$
>   does this iteration correspond to?

My first idea would be to write out this recursion, for example if $n=2$, then

$x_3 = x_2 + \alpha (b-Ax_2) $

$= (x_1 + \alpha(b-Ax_1)) + \alpha(b-A(x_1+\alpha(b-Ax_1))$

$= x_1 + 2\alpha b - 2\alpha Ax_1 - \alpha^2Ab+\alpha^2A^2x_1$

but I don't see a way out of this. Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x_{n+1}=x_n(1-\alpha A)+\alpha b$$
$$x_{n+1}-\frac{b}{A}=x_n(1-\alpha A)+ab(1-\frac{1}{\alpha A})=\left(x_n-\frac{b}{A}\right)\left(1-\alpha A\right)$$

$$x_{n+1}=\left(x_1-\frac{b}{A}\right)(1-\alpha A)^n+\frac{b}{A}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\alpha(b-A x_{n})= x_n+ \alpha r_n$$
Since $x_n$ is in the Krylov subspaces $K_{n}(A,b)$ generated by A and b, then $x_n$ is equal to $q_n(A)b$ for some polynomial q of degree <= n-1, where 
$$ q_n(A)= c_0+c_1A+c_2A^2+ ...+ c_jA^j,j<=n-1.$$
Meanwhile, the residual $r_n = b-Ax_n = b-Aq_n(A)b = (I-Aq_n(A))b.$

This implies:
 $$x_{n+1}= x_n+ \alpha r_n =(c_0+c_1A+c_2A^2+ ...+ c_jA^j)b+\alpha(I-A(c_0+c_1A+c_2A^2+ ...+ c_jA^j))b$$
$$ = \left[(c_0+\alpha)I+ (c_1-\alpha c_0)A+ (c_2-\alpha c_1)A^2+...+(c_{j}-\alpha c_{j-1})A^j-\alpha c_jA^{j+1}\right]b.$$

Therefore the polynomial p(A) at steps n corresponds to 
$$p(A)= (c_0+I)+ (c_1-\alpha c_0)A+...+(c_{j}-\alpha c_{j-1})A^j-\alpha c_jA^{j+1}I,\ j<=n-1.$$

Good luck.